# Steps after appointment booking from USA for UK visa, vfs global registration confusion?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, vfs-global

Hi i submitted my application for uk visit visa for myself and my wife. I booked the appointment and then it took me to a page where it asked me to download files and register with our visa application center partner and purchase labels. I clicked on the register button, it took me to vfs website and then i registered and after putting me and my wife in family group together it started asking me to upload documents ? Now according to the steps in visauk website it does not mention this registration part and document upload part ! What to do as this document upload is also asking tb certificate althought u have lived in usa since 2015.
Can somebody please explain is this registration optional or part of the steps? 
What to do as i dont have tb cert and i am in usa since 2015 ? 
Note: i booked my biometric at uscis Asc not premium . 
Thankyou for your help .

Comment: May I ask how much additional fee VFS charges?

Answer (score 1):

This is an optional step, you may ignore it. TB Certificate is needed if your stay in the UK is beyond 6 months (Ref: https://www.gov.uk/tb-test-visa)

How were you able to reserve appointment with USCIS? Didn't they suspend their service? (Ref: https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/news/service-disruption-message-from-uk-visas-immigration)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to choose 23 April and i also received an email from the VFS that it is something to do with the USCIS and not VFS itself. Maybe by then they might be able to fix the issue. 
In relation to TB i am a Pakistani citizen requesting for 2 year Visit visa but i have been living in US since july 2015. 

According to the website:  
Who does not need to be tested
You will not need a TB test
you lived for at least 6 months in a country where TB screening is not required by the UK, and you’ve been away from that country for no more than 6 months

Answer (score -1):

This is an optional step to my understanding if you're not going with premium locations. You can buy shipping labels on your own. The appointments at USCIS are suspended as of April 11th (I went to mine today and got turned away).
I wonder if the money we paid for appointment will still be fine for re-booking when it is resumed. Hope we won't have to pay again.