# Did USCIS resume its biometric service for UK visa?

Tags: usa, uk, standard-visitor-visas

Service [has been suspended](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/news/service-disruption-message-from-uk-visas-immigration) since Mar 29th. It looks like all the new applicants are allowed to reserve appointment with USCIS for biometrics (see: [Steps after appointment booking from USA for UK visa, vfs global registration confusion?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135313/steps-after-appointment-booking-from-usa-for-uk-visa-vfs-global-registration-co))

Did anyone successfully finish biometric process at USCIS post Mar 29th? Sometimes the website does not get updated, leaving people in the dark.

This information will help the affected people to plan.

Comment: I stay in Pittsburgh and was travelling this week to NY and had accordingly taken biometric appointment for 04/10 at one of the local centers. Now with this center closed, and me returning back to Pittsburgh, it would be so very difficult for me to comeback. Not sure if there is a way where i can 'walk in' the Pittsburgh ASC in lieu of above. Very painful this has become.

Comment: Just went to an ASC enter at Dallas today (04/09). The service is still not resumed. Have no idea when this service will be resumed. I don't understand why they can't email everyone about this in advance to save the trip. Such a waste of time. I guess I will wait a few more days. If still not open, the premium center may be the only option.

Comment: I just went to the ASC center in Seattle today and the service was not resumed; the employee there said they didn't know when the service would resume. Other services in that center e.g. Canada Visa was normal, but the UK visa service was suspended. The date when the VFSGlobal released the news seems to be the same one with original Brexit deadline, the latest deadline for Brexit is 4/12 and I hope the service would resume soon after that or I have to pay $800 to use the premium center...

Answer (score 7):

I too went for an appointment at the USCIS Applicaiton Support Center yesterday (8th April). Right at the reception I was told that for UK visa bio-metrics, the service is suspended and I should keep checking the website 'news' section for updates.

Answer (score 5):

I went for the appointment to a USCIS center yesterday.  They basically told me that services were suspended for non-payment.  So I came back home and found this and other thread on google.  You can still book an appointment but you cannot get biometrics done.  I called the paid no. In the UK as well and they said to keep monitoring the VFA global site for updates.

Answer (score 4):

This service resumed on the 17th April and is no longer considered an issue. VFS has even [deleted the news](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/news/service-disruption-message-from-uk-visas-immigration) from its web site.